# Import module with a callback

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

In my main.js, i have a chunk that I can separate into its own module that sets the timezone for the user after an api call, and regardless of the ajax call (success or fail), I initialize my Vue instance.

main.js:

```
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone/moment-timezone';
moment.tz.setDefault("UTC");
window.Vue.prototype.moment = moment;

let timezone = "UTC";
let userTimezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;

axios.get('/api/timezone-data', {
    params: {
        timezone: userTimezone
    }
}).then(response => {
    // do other stuff
    initVue();
}).catch(error => {
    initVue()
});

// Separate until here into its own module

function initVue() {
   // initialises vue
}
```

I want to learn how can I move this chunk into its separate file and somehow be able to catch when it triggers the `initVue()` methods.

Something like, in my main.js:

```
require('./tz-settings').then(() => {
   console.log('initVue() is called')
})
```

---

Or to be more clear,

```
import tzSettings from './tz-settings';
tzSettings('initVueCalledInTzSettings', () => {
   initVue();

})
```

Comment: What about exporting a function from `tz-settings` that accepts a callback or returns a promise? It'll probably look cleaner and not require you to mix `import` statements and `require` statements. Also worth looking into is if your setup supports the [`finally()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) method on promises.

Comment: @Khauri I'd be happy if you can assist me on that (even just with a pseudo example). Also what do I need to look up to learn about 'import' and 'require' differences because I don't know much about these - don't even know how to search for it.

Comment: search for *MDN import* and/or *MDN export* for documentation of es6 modules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution:

> Based on the comment that initVue is in main.js

```
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone/moment-timezone';

export default function(initVue) {
    moment.tz.setDefault("UTC");
    window.Vue.prototype.moment = moment;
    let timezone = "UTC";
    let userTimezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
    return axios.get('/api/timezone-data', {
        params: {
            timezone: userTimezone
        }
    }).then(response => {
        // do other stuff
        initVue();
    }).catch(initVue);
};
```

of course you could also use Promise `.finally`

```
    }).then(response => {
        // do other stuff
    }).catch(error => {
        // handle the error in some way
    }).finally(initVue);
```

And you would use it like

```
import tzsettings from './tz-settings.js';

tzsettings(initVue).then(() => {
   console.log('initVue() is called')
})
```

---

Though to be honest, why not do

```
export default function() {
    moment.tz.setDefault("UTC");
    window.Vue.prototype.moment = moment;
    let timezone = "UTC";
    let userTimezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
    return axios.get('/api/timezone-data', {
        params: {
            timezone: userTimezone
        }
    }).then(response => {
        // do other stuff
    });
};
```

and use it like

```
import tzsettings from './tz-settings.js';

tzsettings().finally(initVue);
```

Why does `tz-settings` need to know anything about `initVue` at all

Comment: I think you got my question wrong :( My question was keeping the `initVue()` in `main.js` and separate all the other code. And with a callback or promise, catch when `initVue()` is called in my main.js

Comment: well then how would `require('./tz-settings').then(() => {
   console.log('initVue() is called')
})` ever call initVue @senty

Comment: It doesn't - it doesn't even work, it's pseudo code to explain. I just wanted to learn how can I move this chunk outside of my main.js and in my main.js, when the ajax call is done (in it's separate file) catch it in my main.js

Comment: fair enough, I didn't realise initVue was defined in main.js - edited answer

Comment: The last chunk looks very nice - but i get error `Uncaught TypeError: _helpers_tz_settings__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ is not a function`

Comment: Sorry, yours was good - `import tzsettings from './tz-settings.js';` but now I get `Cannot read property 'finally' of undefined` - same for `tzsettings().then()`

Comment: did you `return axios.get('/api/timezone-data', {` .. .the `return` is key

Comment: Thank you! That part works perfectly but I need to do some more learning being able to access export/import data two-way. Any suggestions where I can learn them from? Do I need to study ES6 to understand all these?

Comment: passing a function as per first code would be one way to do it

Comment: And return an object as axios being one of the values? (for from module to main)

Comment: `return an object as axios being one of the values` - not sure I understand, but `return axios.....` returns a Promise ... in the `.then` you could `return {blah:123};` then the promise returned will resolve to `{blah:123}`

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your explanations